# How can I send my mDate object back to CrimeFragment from TimePicker or DatePicker?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Here I'm calling OpenDialog with date argument

//CrimeFragment

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode!= Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    Date date = new Date();
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_DATE:
            date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
                break;
        case REQUEST_TIME:
            date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(TimePickerFragment.EXTRA_TIME);
            break;
    }
    mCrime.setmDate(date);
    updateDate();
}
private void updateDate() {
    mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getmDate().toString());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);
   // SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
   // String date = dateFormat.format(mCrime.getmDate());
    mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
    updateDate();
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            OpenDialog openDialog = OpenDialog.newInstance(mCrime.getmDate());
            openDialog.show(fm,DIALOG_OPEN);

            /*
            //Working code
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getmDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this,REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(fm,DIALOG_DATE);*/
        }
    });
```

in OpenDialog I'm calling either TimePicker or DatePicker and giving value to mDate

```
    //OpenDialog
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_OPEN);
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    adb.setTitle(R.string.open_dialog_title);
    adb.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch (which) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_INDEX:
                    dismiss();
                        // Somehow setTargetFragment
                    DatePickerFragment dialogDate = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mDate);
                    dialogDate.show(fm,DIALOG_DATE);
                    break;
                case TIME_DIALOG_INDEX:
                    dismiss();
                    TimePickerFragment dialogTime = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(mDate);
                    dialogTime.show(fm,DIALOG_TIME);
                    break;
                default:
                    dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    return adb.create();
}
```

and here's my other 2 classes.

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vDate = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
    mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(mDate);

    int year = calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) vDate.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datepicker);
    datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            mDate = calendar.getTime();
            getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
        }
    });
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(vDate)
            .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    Log.d("MyLog","DATE --> Gotta update real(mDate's date) " + mDate);
                }
            })
            .create();
}
```

// TimePicker

```
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vTime = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);
    mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_TIME);
   // somehow need to set timePicker to mDate(hour, minute ? Or not needed
    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) vTime.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(mDate);

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            mDate = calendar.getTime();
            getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_TIME,mDate);
        }
    });
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(vTime)
            .setTitle(R.string.time_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    Log.d("MyLog", "TIME --> Gotta update real(mDate's time) " + mDate);
                }
            })
            .create();

}
```

and my question is how can I send mDate from either from TimePickerDialog or DatePickerDialog back to CrimeFragment ?? Is it possible to setTargetFragment from them to CrimeFragment and handle it in onActivityResult() ?? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the listener pattern. Create an interface in your Dialog class, which the host activity/fragment will implement.

Then in the onAttach of the dialog, retrieve the listener from the host.

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents) shows how to perform this communication. Here is the example on thier page:

```
public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

/* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
 * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
 * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
NoticeDialogListener mListener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}
...
```

}